# Magento 404 after installation

Tags: magento, zend-framework, magento-1.7

I've installed Magento and noticed that accessing `http://localhost/admin` I get 404 but when accessing `http://localhost/index.php/admin` I'm able to access it normaly. By 404 I mean a server error, not the Magento's NoRoute page.

- Cleared the cache and got no success.
- Is there any workaround? Some frontend pages are inaccessible due this same issue.
- Tried installing via command line and web browser. No success with both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activate your wampp server's Apache rewrite module.

Comment: You're right, just forgott mentioning the comments. Published it in my own answer. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

404 = not found.  500 = server error.

If you're getting a 404 without index.php then you need to ensure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled on your server and that you have `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use Web Server Rewrites` set to `Yes`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it had no impact in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting a few hours, just found the solution in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11436027/1239006

Run (in Ubuntu):

```
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

And all problems will disapear!

+1 if I saved your day :D

Answer (score 0):

You didn't copy *.htaccess* file to your installation folder (and probably few other hidden files):

```
.gitignore
.htaccess
.htaccess.sample
.php_cs.dist
.travis.yml
.user.ini
```

So on your Mac machine in terminal

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

Relaunch "Finder" (right click + Alt -> Relaunch)
Grab your hidden files and put them into core folder.